# variable operator to add or subrtact another variable

Tags: php, variables, operators

Im making a php math game where you have equations you need to solve in order to earn score. but heres the problem. i have 4 variables, $x, $y, $op, $b. $x is the first random number, $y is the second random number. $op is the operator which i got from a form. but i want $b to store the answer of $x and $y with the corresponding operator. for example: if $op stores the operator / i want $b to store the value of $x / $y. or if $op stores the operator * i want $b to store the value of $x * $y. how can i acomplish this? i have tried te following:
`$x = $_SESSION["min"]; $y = $_SESSION["max"]; $op = $_SESSION["OP"]; $b = $x. $op. $y;`
but $b just echoes the $y variable.

Comment: The quickest solution would be to use `eval`. But we don't talk about eval, especially if the variables are provided by a user. You could make a `switch` based on the value of `$op` to perform a calculation, if the number of options for `$op` is limited. Or you could look into a third-party evaluator, [this one](https://github.com/NeonXP/MathExecutor) for example.

Comment: Use an associative array that maps operators to functions. `['+' => function($x, $y) { return $x + $y; }, ...]`